# JAVA Assigning integer from readFile into 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to store integers into 2 dimensional array.

1. I have Buffered Reader which read my CityFile (Contain city coordinate) and return int x and y while !line.isEmpty (No problem with this)
2. I want to store this 2 integers (x and y) into multidimensional arraylist as a city coordinate (Need help here) 
   **Actually I am trying to create a city matrix, which contains all x and y integers that is available in my cityFile (Euclidean2d).

My FileReader class

```
public static ArrayList  cities = new ArrayList(); 
.
.

} else if (readingCoordinates) {
            items = line.split("(\\s)+");
            assert( cities.size() + 1 == Integer.parseInt(items[0]));
            x = Integer.parseInt(items[1]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);

            City city = new City(x, y);
            addCity(city);
            .
            .
            .
            }
          }

public static void addCity(City city) {
    cities.add(city);
}
```

My Point class

```
public class City {

int x;
int y;

public City (int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public int getX(){
    return this.x;
}
public int getY(){
    return this.y;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return getX()+", "+getY();
}
}
```

Then i store the point in Arraylist of cities in my FileReader class. 
So in my Arraylist of cities like below

cities[city(x,y), city(x,y), city (x,y), ....]

My Question here, 
Can I manipulate this cities array to Create new Matrix [2 dimensional array] in city[i][j]

my current code is not working,

```
  public double[][] cityMatrix() {

            double[][] cityMatrix = new double[FileReader.cities.size()][2];

            for (int i = 0; i < FileReader.cities.size(); i++)
                            cityMatrix[i][0] = getX();

            for (int i = 0; i < FileReader.cities.size(); i++)
                            cityMatrix[i][1] = getY();

            return cityMatrix;
    }
```

I hope my question is clear. If not, kindly let me know so that i could make it clear again.

Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Why not return an List or Array of [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)?

Comment: I Elliot tq for fast response but i m still editing my question to make it more clear..i want to get all item[1] and item[2] in my CityCoordinate File and store it in 2 dimensional array to build my citymatrix[i][j]. because i want to use it later in other module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method `cityMatrix()` you are using `customerMatrix` and `cityMatrix`. Is that just a typo? Try this method:

```
public double[][] cityMatrix() {
    double[][] cityMatrix = new double[FileReader.cities.size()][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < FileReader.cities.size(); i++){
        City c = FileReader.cities.get(i);
        cityMatrix[i][0] = c.getX();
        cityMatrix[i][1] = c.getY();
    }
    return cityMatrix;
}
```

Comment: Thanks TomasZ. Yes it is typo. i m changing all to cityMatrix. By the way, i have tried suggested method. it make more sense but i still geting error at City c = FileReader.cities.get(i); < incompatible type : Object cannot convert to City. Suggest me to to cast.. get(...) to city  City c = (City) FileReader.cities.get(i); ? What does it mean?

Comment: And Wow..it work now.. just follow what is suggest..alter abit your code suggestion  City c = (City) FileReader.cities.get(i) ..

Comment: You won't need to cast it to `City` if you use `public static ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();`. I am happy I could help :)

Comment: yes. i ve tried it..and it work too...now i understand :). thanks again.